# Format Data from Word Doc to SQL using RegEX

Tags: sql, regex

I have a data table in a Word document that I need to reformat into INSERT SQL statements. I'd like to use RegEx as an advanced find and replace tool to reformat the text. I've tried several combinations of expressions researched online, but nothing quite provides the results I need.

Sample Input:

```
7     John       Doe    987 Main St.              Paris     78945-032       France     SysEng
```

Desired Output:

```
('7', 'John', 'Doe', '987 Main St.', 'Paris', '78945-032', 'France' 'SysEng'),
```

I've figured out how to remove all the random combination of more than two spaces and tabs, but can't quite get it to output like above.

Here's what I've been experimenting with on regex101.com, which contains the full dataset: https://regex101.com/r/4ua8qs/2

Any ideas? I'm sure I'm overlooking a simpler way to do this.

Comment: *I'm sure I"m overlooking a simpler way to do this*: Yep. Any number of ways using parameterized SQL statements and VBA/C# or any language that supports using ActiveX for automation. In the fashion of the TV game show Jeopardy: *What is "How to choose the wrong tool for the job?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with data tables in Word, but surely these date items are already categorised into cells so you just need to pluck the data out of the cells using the Word API and pop them into the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a three-step regex replace approach:

1. add the commas and quotes: [`\t+| {2,}` with `', '`](https://regex101.com/r/4ua8qs/3)
2. fix the start of the string: [`^` with `('`](https://regex101.com/r/4ua8qs/4)
3. fix the end of the string: [`$` with `'),`](https://regex101.com/r/4ua8qs/5)

You may have to escape some of the characters.